# Nested IF with PICKVAL

Tags: formula, nested

I dived into a nested if statement and it's now way over my head. Could you please take a look and let me know why it doesn't work?

All I wantis to categorize our accounts based on multiple criteria. Region, Sector and later on the number of employees. But i've been at it for 2 hours to no avail...

```
IF(
ISPICKVAL( Sector__c, "Supplier/Distributor"), "Supplier", 
IF(
ISPICKVAL( Account_Region__c , "Middle East"), "Middle East",
  IF(
    ISPICKVAL( Account_Region__c , "Americas"), 
      IF(BEGINS(TEXT(Sector__c) , "Restaurants")), "US Restaurants", "US Hotels")))
```

The error message reads:

```
Error: Incorrect number of parameters for function 'IF()'. Expected 3, received 1
```

Many thanks in advance!

Csongor

Comment: Can you add more details on your objective? The formula looks *valid*, as it is. Are you trying to concatenate values from several different fields?

Comment: Not event that - it's a simple formula(text) field that will say various things depending on the picklist values.

Comment: So how is it currently failing? Can you edit your question to add those details?

Comment: ah, good point!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You had a spurious parenthesis resulting in closing an `IF` too early. I think this is what you're aiming at here (note the comment, which you shouldn't include in your formula):

```
IF(
    ISPICKVAL(Sector__c, "Supplier/Distributor"), 
    "Supplier", 
    IF(
        ISPICKVAL(Account_Region__c , "Middle East"), 
        "Middle East",
        IF(
            ISPICKVAL(Account_Region__c , "Americas"), 
            IF(
                BEGINS(TEXT(Sector__c) , "Restaurants"), // Spurious parenthesis was here 
                "US Restaurants", 
                "US Hotels"
            ), 
            "" // Note we need another parameter here
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks David, I'm afraid I still get the following error message after copying your quote without the comments of course:
"Error: Incorrect number of parameters for function 'IF()'. Expected 3, received 2"

Comment: Whoops, I missed that. See my edit. You need a default value for if the account's not in the Americas.

Comment: ABSOLUTELY BRILLIANT! Thank you David, much much appreciated!!!

Comment: Hey David, if you have some time, could you please look at my final piece of the puzzle? Same task, just additional spurious parentheses... Many thanks, Cs
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/219391/spurious-parenthesis-issue-in-nested-if-statement-continued