# Spurious parenthesis issue in Nested IF statement (continued)

Tags: formula, nested

I dived into a nested if statement and it's now way over my head. Could you please take a look and let me know why it doesn't work?

All I wantis to categorize our accounts based on multiple criteria. Region, Sector and later on the number of employees. But i've been at it for 2 hours to no avail...

```
IF(
ISPICKVAL(Sector__c, "Supplier/Distributor"), 
"Supplier", 
IF(
    ISPICKVAL(Account_Region__c , "Middle East"), 
    "Middle East",
    IF(
        ISPICKVAL(Account_Region__c , "Americas"), 
        IF(
            BEGINS(TEXT(Sector__c) , "Restaurants"),
            "US Restaurants", 
            "US Hotels"
        ), 
            IF(
                 AND(NumberOfEmployees < 100, Account_Region__c, "UK"), "Independents"
                IF( 
                     AND(NumberOfEmployees >= 100, NumberOfEmployees < 1750), "UK - SMB",
                   IF(
                       NumberOfEmployees >= 1750, "UK - C&E", "ERROR"
                   )
                )
            )

    )
  )
)
```

The error message reads:

```
Error: Syntax error. Missing ')'
```

I would be very grateful if someone  could help me find the gap!

Thanks,

Csongor

Comment: I don't have the time to dive into this but did notice something that i think is off: AND(NumberOfEmployees < 100, Account_Region__c, "UK"). That probably should be AND(NumberOfEmployees < 100, Account_Region__c ="UK"). Could be that it fixes your problem, but might not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing one comma.

```
IF(
ISPICKVAL(Sector__c, "Supplier/Distributor"), 
"Supplier", 
IF(
    ISPICKVAL(Account_Region__c , "Middle East"), 
    "Middle East",
    IF(
        ISPICKVAL(Account_Region__c , "Americas"), 
        IF(
            BEGINS(TEXT(Sector__c) , "Restaurants"),
            "US Restaurants", 
            "US Hotels"
        ), 
            IF(
                 AND(NumberOfEmployees < 100, Account_Region__c, "UK"), "Independents",
                IF( 
                     AND(NumberOfEmployees >= 100, NumberOfEmployees < 1750), "UK - SMB",
                   IF(
                       NumberOfEmployees >= 1750, "UK - C&E", "ERROR"
                   )
                )
            )

    )
  )
)
```

After `AND(NumberOfEmployees < 100, Account_Region__c, "UK"), "Independents"`

Comment: That's so embarrassing! Thank you for your help :)